# ReactJS/Graphql: How to export the query to use in another component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

For the next phase of this project I need to export the query so I can call it from another component using query variables.  All the examples I have seen do not use the  nor the 'query =', so I am lost on the syntax statement to export the query.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
const UserList = (props) => (
  <Query
    query={gql` 
      query action($timestamp: Float! ){
        action(timestamp: $timestamp){
        action
        timestamp
        object{
          filename
        }
      }
    }
`}

  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

          return (    
            <Item.Group divided>
              {data.action.map(action =>
                <div>
                  <ul>
                  <li>{action.action}</li>
                  <li>{action.timestamp}</li>
                  <ul>
                  {action.object.map( (obj) => {
                    return (<li>{obj.filename}</li>)
                  })}
                  </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}
              </Item.Group>
            );
        }}
  </Query>
);

export default (UserList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const n6dynQuery = gql`
      query action($timestamp: Float! ){
        action(timestamp: $timestamp){
        action
        timestamp
        object{
          filename
        }
      }
    }`
```

use it in component as :-

```
import {n6dynQuery} from "filepath"
const UserList = (props) => (
  <Query query={n6dynQuery} >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

          return (

            <Item.Group divided>
              {data.action.map(action =>
                <div>
                  <ul>
                  <li>{action.action}</li>
                  <li>{action.timestamp}</li>
                  <ul>
                  {action.object.map( (obj) => {
                    return (<li>{obj.filename}</li>)
                  })}
                  </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}

              </Item.Group>
            );
        }}
  </Query>
);

export default (UserList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try it later and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Not sure how to implement this.  I need to call the query from after the submit button is press and have the display update based on the response from the data. What is the syntax to call the query from the submit button?